# how I can display the sidebar first than the content

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

I have a theme its good and fast.
but in mobile mode, it shows the sidebar after the content.
how can i modify that in my theme.
**I just want to display the sidebar before the content, thanks.**

Comment: This topic will come under css tag. You can do this using few lines of css. Check this
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_order

Comment: Just change the place of sidebar DIV and content

Answer (score 0):

You most find **sidebar** div and **main content** div in your theme (html file)

and Just change the place of sidebar DIV and content like this :

```
    <div class="row">
        <!-- sidebar -->
       <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
           <aside>
                your sidebar ... 
           </aside>
        </div>
       <!-- main content -->
       <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
           <main>
               your main content here         
           </main>
        </div>
     </div>
```

in this structure in mobile Sidebar comes first and the main content is then sorted.

but if you want in monitor mode sidebar comes left you can fix by `float:left;`